# JS Synchronous function not executing with small timeout in setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Why does this code not show "You pressed cancel" after the first time cancel is pressed ?

Confirm box not allowing "hi" from displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Confirm Box</h2>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";
        setTimeout(confirmOperation, 0, "Please, press a button!");
      }
      function confirmOperation(message) {
        var txt;
        if (confirm(message) == true) {
          txt = "You pressed OK!";
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
          return true;
        } else {
          txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
          setTimeout(confirmOperation, 0, "Please, press a button!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you immediately run confirmOperation which does not allow time to replace the text with a redraw of the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You are recursive calling the function with 0 seconds delay. Set a slight delay of for example 5mS

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
setTimeout(confirmOperation, 0, "Please, press a button!");
                             ^^
```

change it to

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
setTimeout(confirmOperation, 5, "Please, press a button!");
                             ^^
```

```js
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";
      setTimeout(confirmOperation, 0, "Please, press a button!");
    }

    function confirmOperation(message) {
      var txt;
      if (confirm(message) == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        return true;
      } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
        console.log(txt);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        setTimeout(confirmOperation, 5, "Please, press a button!");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Confirm Box</h2>


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you do not have defined "message" in your function confirmOperation(message).

Secondly, you are using setTimeout(...) wrong. You need to pass it a function and lack the brackets.

Third, you have no eventlistener on your dom element.

Here is a non-pretty jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/kmxr6f21/

```
<h2>JavaScript Confirm Box</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";
  setTimeout(function() {
    confirmOperation("Please, press a button!");
  });
}

function confirmOperation(message) {
  var txt;
  if (message == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    return true;
  } else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    //setTimeout(confirmOperation, 0, "Please, press a button!");
    return false;
  }
}

</script>
```

I hope that helps.